# SSO access to php server with AD authentification

Tags: php, linux, apache, active-directory, kerberos

On a RH 5.3, Apache/2.2.15, mod_auth_kerb is loaded, Active Directory 2008, we want to control access to an url with an authentified user of an AD group member without prompt user/password.

Actually, we can control the access but with prompt user/password - but we doesn't see what parameter must be changed to haven't got the prompt.

### /etc/krb5.conf

```
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 default_realm = DOMAIN.LOCAL

#default_tkt_enctypes = RC4-HMAC,DES-CBC-CRC,DES3-CBC-SHA1,DES-CBC-MD5
#default_tgs_enctypes = RC4-HMAC,DES-CBC-CRC,DES3-CBC-SHA1,DES-CBC-MD5
#dns_lookup_realm = false
#dns_lookup_kdc = false
#ticket_lifetime = 24h
#forwardable = true
#   default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
#   default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5
#   permitted_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc des-cbc-md5


[realms]
domain.local = {
  kdc = MyServer.domain.local
  admin_server = MyServer.domain.local
  default_domain = domain.local
}

[domain_realm]
 .domain.local = DOMAIN.LOCAL
 domain.local = DOMAIN.LOCAL
```

---

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/html/test_CTI/>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    AuthType basic
    AuthBasicProvider ldap

    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
    AuthLDAPUrl "ldap://MyServer.domain.local:3268/OU=myOU,DC=domain,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"

    AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=KerbPHPEXP,OU=MyOU,DC=domain,DC=local"

    AuthLDAPBindPassword "PWD!"

    Require ldap-group cn=G151401-DSUP,OU=myOU,DC=domain,DC=local

    #  AuthType kerberos
    AuthName "Authentification DSUP test "
    Krb5Keytab /etc/httpd/conf/kerb5.ktab
    KrbAuthRealms DOMAIN.LOCAL
    KrbMethodNegotiate on
    KrbServiceName Any
    KrbMethodK5Passwd on
    satisfy any
</Directory>
```

---